# Change number of columns on mouseover

Tags: javascript, html-table, onmouseover, onmouseout

I am trying to replace three td's with a single td on mouseover:
[Sample code in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2zqbs6L1/1/)

```
<html>
  <body>
    <table border="1">
      <tr onmouseover="this.innerHTML='<td colspan=3>ABC</td>'" onmouseout="this.innerHTML='<td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td>'">

        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</body>
```

The mouseover works, but the mouseout is ignored.

Comment: Looks like [this was reported 18 years ago](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=60480) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mouseout` event doesn't work after changing the `innerHTML` of the element. I don't know to explain exactly why.

You can do it by adding the single cell into the html, and toggling the visibilty of the cells.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chx580nm/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will work.

```html
<html>

  <body>
  
  <table border="1" onmouseover="this.innerHTML='<td colspan=3>ABC</td>'" onmouseout="this.innerHTML='<td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td>'">
    <tr>
          <td>A</td>
          <td>B</td>
          <td>C</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
  
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: This behaves awkward for me. Works only sometimes. (Chrome 68.0.3440.106)